# What does the AxisAngleRotation3D.Axis property really mean?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

It might be a silly question but I am new to WPF 3D technology.

Currently I am working on my project using SharpDX (a DirectX wrapper for C#). I am implementing 3D rendering engine and trying to implement the same interface like in WPF. So all meshes, camera position etc. I get from XAML file. Now I am trying to set the center point of model rotation. In SharpDX this property is set by using Vector3 object (x,y,z). In WPF there is no such property but I found Axis property. Can I interpret this property as center of rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the MSDN documentation on the [RotateTransform3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.rotatetransform3d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. For the transform object itself, you can specify a center of rotation and a separate rotation object that describes the mechanism of rotation.

For the rotation object, an [AxisAngleRotation3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.axisanglerotation3d(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used when you desire to specify the angle of rotation and the *alignment* of the axis of rotation (i.e. a vector). The rotation is applied about the axis defined by the center point of the parent transform class and the vector axis of the rotation object.

Alternatively, you can use a [QuaternionRotation3D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.media3d.quaternionrotation3d) object, which allows you to specify a quaternion instead of the axis direction and angle of rotation. A quaternion intrinsically includes both of these. It's often used when one wants to easily interpolate between two orientations (each described as a quaternion-based rotation), something that is more difficult if the rotations to interpolate between are defined as axis/angle.

If you need to emulate a full rotation transform with a specified center using only the axis rotation of SharpDX, then you will need to compose several transformations:

1. Translate the model to the specified center (the center becomes the new origin),
2. Rotate by the specified angle around the specified axis,
3. Translate the model back (the opposite of 1.).